# Datagridview to array missing one row

Tags: c#, linq, toarray, datagridviewrow

I have a `DataGridView` with a `CheckBox` first column.

I use the following Linq to get all the checked rows.

```
DataGridViewRow[] drs = dgvMain.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(x =>(!Convert.IsDBNull(x.Cells[0].Value) && Convert.ToBoolean(x.Cells[0].Value))).ToArray();
```

But somehow the result ALWAYS missing the last checked row!!!

BUT, if I select another roll (not checking it), before I run the line, the last row showed up!!!

Could somebody please be so kind and tell me where did I do wrong!?

Much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are using this condition:

```
!Convert.IsDBNull(x.Cells[0].Value) && Convert.ToBoolean(x.Cells[0].Value)
```

Using `&&` this condition must succeed both left and right.

now my Question is:

```
Convert.ToBoolean(x.Cells[0].Value) 
 => not a boolean? where clause return as false.
 => what is the purpose? this code doesn't have a reason anymore. You are just 
 converting it to boolean
```

I suggest you can try only this:

```
DataGridViewRow[] drs = dgvMain.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(x =>(!Convert.IsDBNull(x.Cells[0].Value)))
```

Comment: The reason I added the second condition is that I "ONLY" want the rows that are "checked"! Without it, it will return "ALL" the rows that ever been "modified"!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the `DataGridView` is still in **Edit Mode** when I ran the code, which means the check is not **"final"**!

That's why the Linq was unable to find it!

So I added

```
dgvMain.EndEdit();
```

before the Linq query and the problem is solved!!!